# hg update over ssh not working (hg clone works well...)

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I have some code on bitbucket.org under mercurial version control. Now I want to download the code on my ubuntu machine over ssh. When I use hg clone everything works well. However hg update never updates any files. I'm not even asked for my ssh password. I checked these setting:

```
ssh -v hg@bitbucket.org
```

-> looks ok.

```
hg showconfig
```

-> path.default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/myrepo...

Do you have any idea what else to check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg update` doesn't contact the remote repo, it pulls changes into the working directory from your local repository.   That's why you are not being asked for your bitbucket password.   Use `hg pull` to get the changes from the remote repo into your local repo, then `hg update`, or just use `hg pull -u` to do both at once.